# ReactJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - LocalForage IndexedDB GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a hard time with a React Example project I am trying to update for training purposes.

The original script uses GraphQL to query database data - I replaced it with LocalForage and try to stick to the original code - however it gives me frequent errors.

It is all about line 58:

```js
    this.setState({items: value})
```

The original line can be seen in 51:

```js
//    .then(data => this.setState({items: data.data.listItems.items}))
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
//import { API, graphqlOperation }  from "aws-amplify";
//import * as queries from '../graphql/queries';
import localforage from 'localforage';


const styles = {
  card: {
    minWidth: 275,
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'inherit',
    padding: '10px'
  },
};

class ListItems extends Component {

state = {
    items: []
  }

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getItems()
  }

getItems = () => {
//    ORIGINAL GraphQL Query from project
//    API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listItems))
//    .then(data => this.setState({items: data.data.listItems.items}))
// ------------------------------------------------------------

//    NEW LocalForage QUERY:
    localforage.getItem('MyDatabaseKey').then(function(value) {
    // This code runs once the value has been loaded
    // from the offline store.
    this.setState({items: value})
}).catch(function(err) {
    // This code runs if there were any errors
    console.log(err);
});



  };

render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { items } = this.state;
    const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={16}>
          {items.map(item => (
             <Grid key={item.id} item>
                 <Card className={classes.card}>
                   <CardContent>
                     <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                       {item.name}
                     </Typography>
                      <Typography component="p">
                      {item.price}
                      </Typography>
                      <br />
                      <Typography component="p">
                      {item.description}
                      </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                     <Button size="small">Edit Item</Button>
                   </CardActions>
                 </Card>
               </Grid>
             ))}
         </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ListItems.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ListItems);
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
at listItems.js:58
```

Hopefully someone of you guys can help me out.

Thank you so much for taking the time!

---

Update 1:

According to Josh I tried:

```js
getItems = () => {
//    ORIGINAL GraphQL Query from project
//    API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listItems))
//    .then(data => this.setState({items: data.data.listItems.items}))
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

//    NEW LocalForage QUERY:
localforage.getItem('MyDatabaseKey')
.then(value => this.setState({items: value}) )
.catch(function(err) {
    // This code runs if there were any errors
    console.log(err);
});
```

However, it gives me another error:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncrtF.png)

Comment: Can you try initializing the `state` in the `constructor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this isn't being referenced correctly inside the promise. Have you tried replacing function(value){//code} with value => //code

It's most likely to do with lexical scoping that arrow functions bring.

Comment: Hey Josh, thanks for your input - just tried, but I am getting another error. Please see the screenshot in the Update Edit. - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: Okay, are you able to print what the state is after calling the function? It might be that `value` that state.item is being set too is not an array

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the binding of "this". in your promise.then you don't have "this" referring to your class components "this".
you can define a function in your class like updateState or whatever you want and then pass it to "then".

example:

```
class ListItems extends Component {
updateState = (value) => {
   this.setState({items: value})
}

getItems = () => {

 localforage.getItem('MyDatabaseKey').then(this.updateState).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});   
  };

}
```